# Pulling server local administrator information to SCCM database

Tags: sccm

I have removed the user from server local administrator group couple of days back.  But its not updated in the SCCM database.  How do I pull the local administrator group information to SCCM database?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

This article will allow you do what you need.

http://eskonr.com/2017/03/sccm-configmgr-report-for-local-admins-and-local-group-members/

Cheers

Joe